# I can access to my wordpress page at work and via cellphone, but when I get home, I can't access to the website

Tags: installation

I used hostgator to help me install a raw Wordpress, address is

> www.nobibiusa.com

I can access to the website at work, through company's Internet and also through my cellphone network. But when I get back home, using my wifi, I can't get access to the site, keeps timing out and giving me error: `'The site cannot be reached'`.

I used my laptop, my wife's laptop, our tablets, none of them work at home under the same wifi network.

There must be some setting going wrong with the home Internet but I could not figure it out. Anyone has the same issue before?

Thank y'all very much.

Comment: This isn't a WordPress related issue, hence the downvote on your question.

Answer (score 0):

The is a DNS or Firewall issue, either on your own network or the network of your Internet provider (ISP).

As it's happening on all of your devices on your home network, I would suggest resetting/restarting your router and if that doesn't help, contact your Internet provider for further help.